# firebase a/b testing version targeting not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-ab-testing

when I try to target a version number in firebase's a/b testing it stays at 0 users for the test. when I do the exact same thing with the audiences, it populates users. I'm confused what's going on here.

[image]

A/B testing: Doesn't work.

[image]

Audience: Works.

What do I do to target a version on firebase a/b test?

Comment: is this an issue for ios or android?

Comment: I'm trying it with iOS and it's not working.

Comment: I also noticed that we didn't get any users when we tried to target iOS by app version.

Comment: @xuzepei answer is correct. I talked with their support - they use build number

Answer (score 2):

**Cause**: According to my testing, the A/B testing condition seems to use build version rather than app version to set the target for iOS.

**Solution:** Set the same version in Xcode as below and use "contains" for the version condition settings.

For example:

[image]